# Attempting to replace shapes with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am very new to js as a whole, and have decided that a good way to get to know  and javascript as a whole would be to follow a tutorial for building a simple block-breaking game.

The game itself runs just fine, however, I would like to find a way to replace the js-drawn circle with an image of a ball, and the blocks with any other rectangular images.

I know (I think) that I need to implement `var img = new Image()`
in some way, but I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing this without managing to make my circle disappear altogether.

I believe the offending area of my code may be this part:

```
function drawBall(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, ballSize, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
```

However, given that I am new, I may have completely missed it , and so I also provide a codepen of the project thus far. [Codepen](http://codepen.io/epicfishboy/pen/MpdWwa)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: Being that this uses the `<canvas>` tag to draw shapes, I suspect the solution you are seeking is non-trivial [See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images) @PHPglue - beat me by 40sec.

Comment: @Forty3 I would imagine the solution is just editing a few lines, however I've tried the methods mentioned on the Mozilla page, but I can't seem to get the image to actually show up in place of the original shape.  
My issue is more with implementation than being unaware of the methods, I'm sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that draws the circle is the following:

```
ctx.arc(x, y, ballSize, 0, Math.PI*2);
ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
ctx.fill();
```

So instead of drawing a circle (which is done with the `.arc`), you can draw an image instead using the `.drawImage` method. [See docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage). It would look something like this:

```
ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);
```

The image argument is an "image source", which could be just a plain `<img>` element in your HTML. See examples of how to its done in the docs that I linked.

Comment: Yes - what @Arnelle-Balane said. Here is a [Code-Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpVqYO) forked from the original with the example.